# Javascript JSON.stringify method removes trailing zero if object has value as x.0 ( like 6.0 )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

Javascript method JSON.stringify method removes trailing zero. Do we have any other javascript library where JSON.stringify does not removes
trailing zero.

`console.log(JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6.0 }));`
output
'{"x":5,"y":`6`}'

Expected output
'{"x":5,"y":`6.0`}'

Notice .0 after 6 is missing in actual output.

What can be done so that trailing zero is not missed.

Comment: Number values cannot have trailing decimal zeros. Use a string instead.

Comment: Nothing to do with `JSON.stringify`. Try `console.log(6.0)`, you'll get the same result

Comment: JavaScript does not distinguish between int and float. So, `6.0 === 6`. It is accurate as far as JS is concerned.

Comment: Try `console.log( {"x":5,"y":6.0} )`, you'll see that the y value is really just `6`, and it's before you even call JSON.stringify